# Algolia docs search DocSearchModal issue in chrome browser

Tags: css, reactjs, algolia

guys currently using the Algolia search package in my project but facing some problem in Chrome/edge browser but work perfectly in Firefox. and the problem is when we are at the top of the page on the mobile screen when we click on the search button the Doc Search Modal appears correctly in full screen (look for screenshot 1 for the demo) but when we scroll down then the modal does not appear correctly in screen (look in screenshot 2)

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

code -

```
export function MobileSearch({ apiKey, indexName, appId }) {
  const searchButtonRef = React.useRef(null)
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false)
  // const [initialQuery, setInitialQuery] = React.useState(null)

  const onOpen = React.useCallback(() => {
    setIsOpen(true)
  }, [setIsOpen])

  const onClose = React.useCallback(() => {
    setIsOpen(false)
  }, [setIsOpen])

  return (
    <>
      <DocSearchButton ref={searchButtonRef} onClick={onOpen} />
      {isOpen &&
        createPortal(
          <DocSearchModal
            apiKey={apiKey}
            indexName={indexName}
            appId={appId}
            onClose={onClose}
            initialScrollY={window.scrollY}
            // initialQuery={initialQuery}
          />,
          document.body,
        )}
    </>
  )
}
```